# Android emulator not showing up on desktop screen

Tags: android, emulation, android-virtual-device

I encounter really strange behavior with android emulator. First of all, I am using extended monitor for development. So i code on my laptop and check the app on emulator on second screen. For some reason, I can't see emulator again after disconnect vga cable but I can see emulator is running on taskbar. Somehow, I can't bring emulator out on desktop screen or move to another screen, it just hidden and I don't know how to bring it out. It already happens to me two or three times. Can somebody help me out? What can I do to solve it? 
Below is screenshots of my desktop with emulator running.

[alt+tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjasC.png)

[avd manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfbez.png)

Comment: What is your OS ??

Comment: It's off-screen, press ALT+SPACE when hoovering the icon on the task bar and press "move"

Comment: it's window 10 home @Ben-J

Comment: What i always do to solve this issue is delete old emulator and recreate again.

Comment: @Zoe I already try that method.

Comment: Please tell me why it is down voted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens again when I change to another monitor for extended screen. I try what @Zoe suggested press ALT+SPACE to move but it doesn't work because move is grey out.

> So my solution, I created two emulators, for two different monitors.

I am not sure why I got downvoted though.